Edit part of GitHub Pages via Action without overwriting?
My project currently has this GitHub Action configuration to automatically publish documentation from main:
      - name: Upload Cargo doc output to GitHub Pages
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
        with:
          path: target/doc
  deploy:
    name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4

I'd like to support also publishing docs for each PR in a sub-directory (e.g., /pulls/123/). IIUC, if I do that using this flow, I'll end up clobbering the entire contents of the site, which I don't want to do - I want the contents generated via the Action running on main to remain. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Idea 1: Rebuild the docs everytime there is a PR
That means building the entire docs from source when you just want to add a PR. That is inefficient in terms of build time.
Idea 2: Use a separate branch for generated docs
When you build the main docs, push it to a separate repository like pages, and have an action to deploy when there are changes to pages. Also, when you want to add a PR, just add that as a commit to pages, which will trigger the build action.
